# Deleting Favorited Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hy guys I have a problem when deleting the cell.

First I added a custom UIButton on every cell and when the button is executed it saves item in UserDefaults and it shows as painted heart img I fetch saved item in another controller but when I delete the item UIButton image stays the same. I do not know how to put button to default state(image).

First of I created as I sad the custom UIButton

```
lazy var favoriteButton: UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "herzfavorie").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .white
     return button
    }()
```

this btn selector "handleTapped" saves item in User Defaults and makes animation

```
let key = "key"



 @objc func handleTapped() {

   guard  let product = self.product else { return }

  let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: listOfPodcasts)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)

        var listOfPodcasts = Product.savedProducts()

        listOfPodcasts.append(product)

        self.showHeartLiked()


    }
```

[that saves the item in User Defaults and creates this effect on cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqxGF.png)
but later on when I delete the product in this func

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let removalProduct = savedProducts[indexPath.row]

    let tableViewAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (_, _) in

       self.savedProducts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    Product.deleteProducts(product: removalProduct)
```

}
after this func button should be as by default

[button should be as by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQdZ.png)

but the button stays not by default I hope I explained it well when someone know the solution how to after deleting put back the button to default state I will be grateful

Comment: Add `cellForRowAt` data source method

Comment: This saved products are fetched not in same controller. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NotificationCenter from your list view controller to alert other view controller for change button style.

Comment: I tried that but it delets for all cells I want to delete only for item which I deleted

Answer (score 0):

you can manage it by the button's state.
set Normal heart image for normal state and filled heart image for the Button's selected state.

Now when user clicks on button you can save the data and make button state selected so it will show the filled heart image.

also when you are deleting the particular cell, at that time you can user Notification center to fire notification or use custom delegate to inform another view controller about the changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I tried NotificationCenter  after deleting the product but it delets all heart images for all cells I want to delete and default the button just on one cell that I deleted but I am not sure how to pass delegate from tableviewcontoller ( controller where saved items are listed ) to cells custom button

Comment: you can pass index of that cell on which you are working with notification, and just delete heart for that index only

Comment: Yes I will, but before that let me know how you are managing the 1st view controller, I mean based on what you are showing the heart is filled or not, because this is the main logic point in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it , I checked if the product is favorited through index(where: ...).  in cellForItemAt and after deleting the product I used Notification where I only called self.collectionView.reloadData()
And it works perfectly fine